# Employer search on SO Careers appears broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

If I put 'idiot' in the location text box while searching as an employer, it says '4 candidates found'?

Edit: Putting anything which is likely to give 0 candidates, such as 'kjhhjfkjfn', 'jewygfweuyg', etc in the location, also shows '4 candidates found'. So is the search designed to always show '4 candidates found' even when there are no candidates found?

Edit: [Screenshot here](http://i48.tinypic.com/1zx4ivt.png).

Edit 2: Only when I move the focus away from the location textbox, a box saying 'we're not sure where this is, click to dismiss' shows up. But :

1) It should say 0 candidates instead of 4 candidates to the right side of the search form.

2) Why wait until the focus is moved away from the textbox?

Comment: maybe post a screenshot of your *exact* search selections?

Comment: So those boxes are checked before you type?

Comment: I think you're seeing 4 candidates from your saved query (we save the last thing you queried that worked). Until you tab AWAY from the field, nothing is searched -- you're viewing the count from your PREVIOUS search.

Comment: No, what I did was, I went to the page, it showed '--' candidates, then I typed in the gibberish in location textbox and hit enter. I saw the spinning graphic next to the count, and then it said 4 candidates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Yahoo's Geolocation service through YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to map arbitrary text -- *any* arbirary text -- to location coordinates.

Apparently that maps to a location of some kind.

Garbage in, garbage out. (shrug)

edit: I can't even repro this, so I really have no idea what you're talking about. When I type in "idiot" in the Location field, I get

> We aren't sure where this is, be a little more specific
>   (click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: I've tried it several times, it still shows '4 candidates found' for idiot for me. Must be random somehow?

Comment: No. Blame someone else.

Comment: screenshot added